# Opening a VSTO document level customized template from Onedrive for business

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-word, vsto, word-addins

My issue is, I developed a VSTO Word Template (document-level). Everything was pretty smooth. I also deployed my template. But the problem is, I can easily save the documents in Onedrive for business, but if I open the same document from there, it says that the document is not in a trusted location and it opens the document but does not load the customized tools. I also [read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/architecture-of-document-level-customizations?view=vs-2022#:%7E:text=If%20the%20document,process%20stops%20here.) that the document level customized template does not load the tools if the document is in an untrusted location. Is there any way of opening those documents with the customized tools from Onedrive for business? Or is it not possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. You may consider creating an installer for your solution. See how to [Deploy an Office solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution?view=vs-2022).

Also you may consider create an application-level add-in, so when users open any documents your add-in will be available and can do the required customizations. You may pay your attention to the new web add-in for Word, see how to [Build your first Word task pane add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/word-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator). The solution can be run on multiple platforms as well as in web browsers.